# Middle mouse button and right mouse button on a Zelotes T80 gaming mouse both click at the same time

Tags: windows-10, mouse

Since the day I got my mouse (Zelotes T80 gaming mouse) both the right button and the middle button are linked. By that I mean that when I click on the right mouse button, it acts like I also clicked on the middle mouse button, and vice versa.

I'd like to seperate the two, and if that's not possible (faulty mouse), to completely disable the middle click.

I'm using a Zelotes T80 gaming mouse and my driver does not have a feature for remapping the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from third party tools like AutoHotKey pretending to press both, there is no reason AT ALL for a mouse to behave like this.

It will more than likely be a faulty mouse. The physical buttons may be catching on each other or distorting the circuit board the switches are mounted on.